# What's the (n-1)th term

Tags: sequences-and-series

$S_n = 1+ 3x^2 + 5x^4 + 7x^6+ ....(2n-1)x^{2n-2}$

(a) Write down the $(n-1)$-th term.

(b) Write down series for $x^2 S_n$.

I don't even know where to start. I can't find the common ratio and is $a=1$?Is this even a G.P.?

Comment: This is not a geometric progression.

Comment: Replace $n$ with $n-1$ in the pattern you just wrote. Done.

Comment: Do i substitute n-1 into (2n-1)x^(2n-2)?

Answer (score 1):

$S_n = 1+ 3x^2 + 5x^4 + 7x^6+ ....(2n-1)x^{2n-2}$

What is the first term :  1

What is the second term : $3x^{2}$

What is the third term : $5x^{4}$

.

.

.

What is the $(n-1)^{th}$ term : $(2n-3)x^{2n-4}$

For the second question,

Let $C_{n}=x^{2}S_{n}$, Then

$C_n = x^{2}+ 3x^4 + 5x^6 + 7x^8+ ....(2n-1)x^{2n}$

Comment: Okayy thanks a lot